# Nothing work in Android Studio 3.6.3 after creating a new project

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

i am running the version 3.6.3 of android studio, today, after creating a new project, the project don't build or sync, i tried changing the gradle from 'gradle-wrapper.properties' file, to specified location but it doesnt work. 
[image]

Comment: Did you try clean the project and then rebuilding it? looks like there is no run configuration present. Please add your gradle build files, the run configurations you have and the error if you get any.

Comment: @ShakilAhmedShaj thank you so much, i did  "invalidate cache and restart " and that worked, you can added as answer if you want :)

Comment: it would be nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wait some time to finish the background download, then go to `file -> invalidate cache and restart`